# Test run results of VSTest.Console.exe not getting associated to Test Plan

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager, vstest

Upon running the *vstest.console.exe* command mentioned below,

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Products\Engineering\ACOE\EEDemo\ParallelExecution\ParallelExecution\bin\Debug\ParallelExecution.dll /Settings:C:\Products\Engineering\ACOE\EEDemo\ParallelExecution\Parallel1.runsettings /Parallel /Platform:"x64" /TestCaseFilter:"Name~Test" /Logger:TfsPublisher; Collection=http://rdtfs01:8080/tfs/Engineering; TeamProject="ACoE"; Platform="Any CPU"; Flavor="Release"; RunTitle="Sample Project"; BuildName="20170928.1"
```

The output obtained is

> "Publish completed successfully. Test Results: mtm://rdtfs01:8080/tfs/Engineering/p:ACoE/Testing/testrun/open?id=5360."

As a next step, if we try opening the test result file using the above generated link, it externally opens the report in MTM however does not link with any of the test plan. (Please find the image attached).

However if we next close the report and open

> Microsoft Test Manager >> Testing Center >> Test >> Analyze Test Runs

we do not find the report.

This is because of the test run results have not been associated with the TestPlanId in the Database ( Please find the DB screenshot attached ).
Is there a way where we can associate testplan with the output result file generated, so that if an end-user opens the

> Microsoft Test Manager >> selects test plan >> Testing Center >> Test Tab >> Analyze Test Runs

will allow user to see the current results?

Comment: Seems you have forget to upload the screenshot. Are you using the TFS build or just simply use the vstest command from command line, if you are using the TFS build, which TFS build are you using ? vNext or XAML build ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using `vstest.console.exe` command line and  use it with `/logger:TfsPublisher`  which lets you publish the results to the tfs server against a build & test runs **show up on the build page.**

Published results report can be viewed in Microsoft Test Manager or through build reports from Visual Studio and Web access. Test results can be published through TfsPublisher only for the current test run. More details please refer this blog: [Publishing test results through command line test runner](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner/)

> For tests that you run from a test plan **by using Microsoft Test
>   Manager** you can review your test results, assign a reason for a
>   failed test, and assign a resolution.
>
> For tests that you run from the Visual Studio, you can save and then
>   reopen your test results to analyze them. You can also publish these
>   test results to Team Foundation Server. **However, these test results
>   are not used in the pre-defined test reports and cannot be associated
>   with a test plan.**
>
> *Source Link: [Reviewing Test Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182493(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Since you are using the `vstest.console.exe` to run the tests and publish test results to TFS, it's just using Visual Studio, so it's not able to assoicate the result with Test plan in MTM.